# Regular expression to escape n # except 2 #

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to override Parsedown's markup to only allow `<h2>` headings.

What regex would escape all heading types except `<h2>`?

```
#Heading -> \#Heading
##Heading -> ##Heading
###Heading -> \###Heading
####Heading -> \####Heading
#####Heading -> \#####Heading
######Heading -> \######Heading
```

Comment: Thanks, why was this voted as too broad though?

Comment: Rather https://regex101.com/r/uS6xY8/2

Comment: you should post your attempt..

Comment: I honestly had no idea how to start lol.. not that good with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^(?!##\w)(?=#)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS6xY8/4)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^       #Start of string
(?!     #Negative lookahead(it means, whatever is there next do not match it)
 ##\w   #Assert that its impossible to match two # followed by a word character
)
(?=     #Positive lookahead
 #      #check if there is at least one #
)
```

**NOTE**

```
\w denotes any character from [A-Za-z0-9_].
[..] denotes character class. Any character(not string) present in this will be matched.
```

Comment: For whatever reason, the regex isn't working with PHP's preg_replace... that includes all of the other answers here. `preg_replace('/^(?!##\w)(?=#)/m', '\\', $article->body)`

Comment: @frosty can `###...` be present in middle of string?

Comment: Oh... I just realised the headings are linkified. So they actually start with `[` not a `\w` character

Comment: @frosty an example please..you can try `^(?!##\[)(?=#)`

Comment: They might not also be linkified. How is this?: `^(?!##[a-zA-Z0-9\[])(?=#)`

Comment: @frosty try `^(?!##(?!#))(#+)`

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```
^((?:#|#{3,})[^#])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Replace with:** `\$1`

This regular expression will do the following:

- match one hash
- match 3 or more hash

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/kE4oK6/1

**Sample text**

```
#Heading
##Heading
###Heading
####Heading
#####Heading
######Heading
```

**Sample Matches**

```
\#Heading
##Heading
\###Heading
\####Heading
\#####Heading
\######Heading
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      #                        '#'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      #{3,}                    '#' (at least 3 times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^#]                     any character except: '#'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Use look aheads for headings, but not double hashes:

```
 ^(?!##\w)(?=#+)
```